# from data to controller and passing it to form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I'm doing my first steps in mvc and I need help.
I'm passing data from view to this controller and I need to pass the selected items with there details to a different view (that is a form that the user add his email details) and I cant figure out how to .
This is how I'm getting the details to the controller from the submitted form

```
    public ActionResult list()
    {
        var AllItems = db.menu.ToList();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Menu, SelectableMenu>();

        return View(AllItems.Select(m => new SelectableMenu { price = m.price, MenuId = m.MenuId, Name = m.Name })
        .ToList());
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult List(IEnumerable<SelectableMenu> item)
    {
        var userSelectedMenu = item.Where(m => m.IsSelected).Select(m => m.Name + m.price + m.MenuId);
        if (userSelectedMenu != null && userSelectedMenu.Any())
        {
            return View("bla");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method `ReditectToActionstring actionName, string controllerName, Object routeValues)`

for details go to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can return different view using `return View("ViewName",model)`

For eg:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult List(IEnumerable<SelectableMenu> item)
{
    var userSelectedMenu = item.Where(m => m.IsSelected).Select(m => m.Name + m.price + m.MenuId);
    if (userSelectedMenu != null && userSelectedMenu.Any())
    {
        return View("YourDiffrentViewName",userSelectedMenu); // This will pass your model to your Different view
    }

    return View();
}
```

Then in your new view you will have to strongly typed it with your model.

For eg :

Your view will be as follows:

```
@model ProjectName.models.YourClassName //Your class/model namespace

 @using(Html.BeginForm())
 {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Property) //This will create textbox for your property
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
}
```

For more on stronly typed views visit:

1. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/strongly-typed-views-in-mvc/
2. http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnViews/BuildingAStronglyTypedView

Comment: return View("xyz", userSelectedMenu);@model IList<lamb.Models.SelectableMenu>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.Name 
} The Error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[lamb.Models.SelectableMenu,System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[lamb.Models.SelectableMenu]'.

Comment: The problem is that I need to review the selected data from the last form and then add a few more fields

Comment: In this case create the new `view model` which will have all the necessary properties you need on the view and bind this new model to view so now you will have all the necessary info in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You will need twosteps for this

**Step 1**

Make a model(it is more effective) use it in a view to pass your data to controller through post in submission of form.

**Step 2**

Receive the data into the controller method then use
  `return View("yourNewpage","yourdatamodelobject");` in the controller action to pass the data in the action result view of another page.

**Alternatively**,  if the view is in another controller

then you can receive data here in the post action method and use Return `RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", "DataModelObject")` to pass to a diffrent controller

Comment: as I say i 'm doing my first steps in mvc so it look promising but I need more detail  
(what I did was rubbish)